# Pythonic way to work with multiple linux machines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write a framework which has capability to entaract with multiple linux machines.

For example my test case which is going to use that framework can be able to start a server in a linux machine, start a client in another linux machine and then should be able to make some configuration  changes in a different linux machine without waiting for any command to complete.

I have tried using `pexpect` to do my job but didn't find it more useful.

**Can anyone suggest me any Python module which i can use to do my task ?**

My Testcase steps are like:

```
1. Login to SIP Server -> su -> start SIP server
2. Login to Voice Server -> su -> make some configuration changes
3. Login to SIP client -> su -> start SIP client
4. Collect logs and perform validations
```

In my environment I can't login into my machines directly as su.

Comment: You might want to look into Chef or Puppet--make sure they're not closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using something like [python-fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) It allows you to use higher level language constructs such as context managers and makes the shell more usable with python in general.

Example usage:

**fabfile.py**

```
from fabric.api import run

def host_type():
    run('uname -s')
```

Then you can use `host_type` from the commandline in the directory of `fabfile.py`:

```
$ fab -H localhost,linuxbox host_type
[localhost] run: uname -s
[localhost] out: Darwin
[linuxbox] run: uname -s
[linuxbox] out: Linux
```

Comment: is fabric able to maintain sessions for a machine after performing some actions into it ?

Comment: Please edit your post with a usecase. It won't maintain sessions but maintaining sessions should not be necessary. I have used fabric for complex multi machine orchestrations ( 50+ machines)